# Reused GMSMapView works on first use, but not on any further ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have several ViewControllers which display a map, so I extracted the common map logic into `MapViewController`:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces

class MapViewController : UIViewController {

var locationService: CLLocationManager!
var placesClient: GMSPlacesClient!
var marker: GMSMarker!
var camera: GMSCameraPosition!
var animatedMarkerImage: UIImage!
var markerImage1: UIImage!
var markerImage2: UIImage!
var markerImage3: UIImage!
var markerImage4: UIImage!
var markerImages: [UIImage]!

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationService = LocationService.shared
    placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()

    markerImage1 = UIImage(named: "Location 01@3x")
    markerImage2 = UIImage(named: "Location 02@3x")
    markerImage3 = UIImage(named: "Location 03@3x")
    markerImage4 = UIImage(named: "Location 04v@3x")
    markerImages = [markerImage1, markerImage2, markerImage3, markerImage4]
    animatedMarkerImage = UIImage.animatedImage(with: markerImages, duration: 1.5)

    do {
        if let styleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "mapStyle", withExtension: "json") {
            mapView.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(contentsOfFileURL: styleURL)
        } else {
            NSLog("Unable to find mapStyle.json")
        }
    } catch {
        NSLog("One or more of the map styles failed to load. \(error)")
    }
  }
}

extension MapViewController : CLLocationManagerDelegate {


func startReceivingLocationChanges() {
    let authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

    if authorizationStatus != .authorizedWhenInUse && authorizationStatus != .authorizedAlways {
        return
    }

    if !CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        return
    }

    locationService.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
    locationService.distanceFilter = 100.0
    locationService.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,  didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations.last!
    if marker == nil {
        camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 14.0)
        marker = GMSMarker()
        let markerView = UIImageView(image: animatedMarkerImage)

        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
        marker.iconView = markerView
        marker.map = mapView
        marker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.pop
        mapView.camera = camera
    } else {
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(1.0)
        marker.position = location.coordinate
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    if let error = error as? CLError, error.code == .denied {
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        return
    }
    print("Location error: \(error)")
  }
}
```

I have three different ViewControllers that inherit from this MapViewController and override each `viewDidLoad()` as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationService.delegate = self
    startReceivingLocationChanges()
}
```

The map and marker display properly and the camera moves to the correct location for the first ViewController, but any subsequent ViewController that inherits from MapViewController just displays the UK.

Putting a breakpoint in `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,  didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])` reveals that the first ViewController receives updated locations, but the following ViewControllers do not.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Where is `LocationService` defined?

Comment: @SteveO'Connor in LocationService I just expose a shared CLLocationManager instance: `static let shared = CLLocationManager()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `LocationService` exposes one instance of `CLLocationManager`. It's `delegate` is assigned to whichever was the last viewController to load. Which is why the other viewControllers are not receiving updates. I would make `LocationService` conform to `CLLocationDelegate` and set it's delegate to itself. Then add an `updateLocation` function to `MapViewController` which handles the map updates.

```
func updateLocation(location: CLLocation){
if marker == nil {
        camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 14.0)
        marker = GMSMarker()
        let markerView = UIImageView(image: animatedMarkerImage)

        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
        marker.iconView = markerView
        marker.map = mapView
        marker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.pop
        mapView.camera = camera
    } else {
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(1.0)
        marker.position = location.coordinate
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

In your `LocationService` update the controllers by calling `updateLocation`

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,  didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations.last!
    viewController1.updateLocation(location: location)
    viewController2.updateLocation(location: location)
    viewController3.updateLocation(location: location)
}
```

Another way to do this is to give each `MapViewController` a different instance of `CLLocationManager` (not shared) but this is not achieving your idea of reusing. As the `CLLocationManager` is accessing a single location service on the device it, each instance of `CLLocationManager` will be doing the same work 3 times. Hope this helps.